# Bootstrap navigation toggle for mobile

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, web

I used a Bootstrap template to start of my website. I added a navlogic and did some adjustment on the logo in an own CSS. Now, when i try my website on mobile , it resizes but when I click on the button nothing happens. I serached for some answers on StackOverflow an someone wrote to look in the console, so I did. It says

> "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found)"

with both http://localhost/onair/js/jquery.js and http://localhost/onair/js/bootstrap.min.js. I'm very confused because when I start the original template everything works fine. Can anyone help me with this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">

<title>Scheduler</title>

<!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Custom CSS -->
<link href="css/logo-nav.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>

<body>

    <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse"
                    data-target="#collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span
                        class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span
                        class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"> <img src="res/logo.png" alt="">
                </a>
            </div>
            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="?site=scheduler">Zeitplan</a></li>
                    <li><a href="?site=profile">Profil</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container -->
    </nav>

    <!-- Page Content -->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
               <?php require_once 'navlogic.php'; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: we can't see localhost files, they're local. Can you show some real code?

Comment: The both links are the scripts from bootstrap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The responsive navbar requires the [collapse plugin](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse), I believe this is the problem.

Comment: I linked the JQuery script as well as the JavaScript Script in my code. These actually are the both links from the console that can not be found. I took the exact same code from the template and just did some adjustment.

Comment: You are testing the Web that is in a local server, with your mobile? the localhost is different in your mobile and in your server, so the url that reference the js not correct, you could use a relative path.

Comment: I'm not actually using my mobile, I'm just zooming in on my browser.

Comment: The problem is the path, are you really sure you have both files jquery.js and bootstrap.min.js in js folder and js folder is at the same level that the html file?

Comment: Damn, you're right. I put the script folder in the res folder. Thank you :)